# Tweepy user_timeline takes 1 position but 2 were given error

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm making a bot that prints the Tweets from a specific user using the `user_timeline`, but it gives me this error when I run it.

```
TypeError: user_timeline() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

This is my full code; obviously I deleted the keys and tokens

```py
# import the module
import tweepy
  
# assign the values accordingly
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
  
# authorization of consumer key and consumer secret
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
  
# set access to user's access key and access secret 
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
  
# calling the api 
api = tweepy.API(auth)
  
# screen name of the account to be fetched
screen_name = "geeksforgeeks"
  
# fetching the statuses
statuses = api.user_timeline(screen_name)
  
print(str(len(statuses)) + " number of statuses have been fetched.")
```

Comment: According to the [source-code](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py#L532), `API.user_timeline` only accepts keyword-arguments: `def user_timeline(self, **kwargs):`

Comment: The function call `api.user_timeline(screen_name)` is giving an error because the method is not expecting `screen_name` as a parameter. Leave it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [source-code](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py#L532) you have to use keyword-arguments with the method `API.user_timeline`.

So change this line:

```
statuses = api.user_timeline(screen_name)
```

Into:

```
statuses = api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Tweepy v4.0.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0) changed [`API.user_timeline`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.0/api.html#tweepy.API.user_timeline) to not accept any positional arguments.
The 1 positional argument being referred to in the error is `self`.
You can pass `screen_name` as the `screen_name` keyword argument instead.